# You can't edit this app until you create a new app release declaring sensitive permissions

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I am having difficulty republishing my app. I keep getting a nonsensical error every time I upload a new APK:

> You can't edit this app until you create a new app release declaring
>   sensitive permissions

Background:

- My app previously requested the READ_SMS permission
- GooglePlay issued a policy update commanding that all developers remove SMS support from their apps or be banned
- I temporarily unpublished the app for several weeks because I did not have time to do the updates
- Last weekend, I removed the SMS permissions from the manifest and uploaded the app, but did not republish it
- Today, I decided to republish the app but there is a grey warning icon next to the release saying "You can't edit this app until you create a new app release declaring sensitive permissions"
- I decided to increase the version number and upload again. However, it asks me to fill out a form asking why I am using the permissions: READ_SMS, RECEIVE_MMS and SEND_SMS

Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foo.bar">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    ...
</manifest>
```

This is an example of the screen I am shown after I upload the app:

[image]

I cannot find any sensible way to answer the questions because they are all asked from the perspective that I am declaring the READ_SMS, RECEIVE_MMS and SEND_SMS in the manifest which I am not.

I spoke to GooglePlay tech support, but they did not understand why it was happening either. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: "Here is my manifest" -- check your merged manifest, such as via the "Merged Manifest" sub-tab in the Android Studio manifest editor. Beyond that, [we cannot help with policy decisions of app distribution channels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: Thank you Mark, that is a big help. The app is a substantial project that includes dozens of other modules, one of them requires all the SMS permissions. Since I still require these modules and permissions for the non-GooglePlay versions of the app, I will have to think about what structure to use.

Comment: The solution I am using for now is to add the following lines to my app manifest:
  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
    tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"
    tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
    tools:node="remove"/>